# How can I filter a datatrame with a column containing 2 values(Y and N), and then sum of count in other column based on filtered (Y and N values)

Tags: r, dplyr, knitr, tidyr, kableextra

I have 4 columns `quarter_intake` `mic_report`  `Report Status`  `Count`. Column `quarter_intake` has 2018 Q1, 2018 Q2, 2018 Q3, 2018 Q4, 2019 Q1. The column `mic_report` has 2 distinct values(Y and N). Column `Report Status`  has MIC Reports in Screening, MIC Reports Received, MIC Reports Screened Out. Column `Count` has various counts based each `quarter_intake`, `mic_report`, `Report Status`. I want the total count based on  based on each Y and N in present in "mic_report" based on each "Report Status" for each Quarter. After the desired result, I want to use the result as a table to produce word document using `Knitr` package

I tried using gather function but not able to move forward

```
mic_reports_received_statewide_summary_all_reports <- ane_reports_received_statewide_summary %>% 
  tidyr::gather(c(3:5), key = "Report Status", value = "Count")
```

Comment: can you make it clear by creating your information table

Comment: To help someone help you, you should include a minimal example of the data in your data frame, and the desired output from that minimal example.